# How to convert an integer with n decimal places to a float

Tags: javascript

I have this integer

7839486009458047182

I have a variable that tells me this number should have n decimal places (In this case 18)

How can I change it to 7.839486009458047182

(If React has this as a method I could use in a template that's even better!)

Comment: just divide it by `10 ** thatnumber`? (where `**` is JS syntax for "to the power of")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not too bothered about precision, you can simply divide the integer by `10 ** decimals`, for example:

```js
console.log(7839486009458047182 / (10 ** 18));
// ^ 7.839486009458047
```

Mind that floats have limited precision. If precision is key, keep it as an integer (or bigint). If it's just for display purposes, then a small amount of imprecision shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the integer by 10 raised to the number of decimal places.

```js
let integer = 7839486009458047182

function setDP(number, decimalPlaces) {
  return number / 10 ** decimalPlaces
}

console.log(setDP(integer, 18))
```